# How to create a static library with g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

Can someone please tell me how to create a static library from a .cpp and a .hpp file? Do I need to create the .o and the .a? I would also like to know how can I compile a static library in and use it in other .cpp code. I have `header.cpp`, `header.hpp .` I would like to create `header.a`. Test the header.a in `test.cpp`. I am using g++ for compiling.

Answer (score 140):

Create a .o file:

```
g++ -c header.cpp
```

add this file to a library, creating library if necessary:

```
ar rvs header.a header.o
```

use library:

```
g++ main.cpp header.a
```

Comment: g++  test.cpp header.a -o test,no?

Comment: @linuxx only if you want to create an executable called `test`, something you should never do. Without the -o flag, an executable called a.out will be created. Us old Unix programmers like it that way.

Comment: @unapersson: Why? The executable is _not_ in `a.out` format so this is highly misleading. And why should you "never" create an executable called `test`?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I guess this has to do with the fact that `test` is a system command. But since test programs usually never are installed in the system bin directory and require you to write `./test` it is not that much a problem to me either...

Comment: @Tomalak Because test is a shell built-in and if you don't run the program explicitly as ./test (which you will inevitably fail to do) you will pick it up instead of your program, with extremely confusing results. And are you saying that the command does not produce an executable called a.out?

Comment: Anyway, the point is, you can call your output executable anything you like, or leave it as the default by omitting the `-o` parameter entirely. You are not bound by strict constructs that you might have been [poorly] taught at school, like "you must write `g++ A.cpp B.a -o A`".

Comment: @unapersson: No. I'm saying exactly what I said. Executables are no longer produced in `a.out` format, but the name remains for legacy reasons. (And if you're incapable of using a shell properly then that's your problem; I for one know how to run an executable from the current directory. `test` is _just fine_ for an executable name, as long as you're writing just a quick test snippet of course.)

Comment: @Tomalak Please point out where I said anything about "a.out format". An as someone who has trained literally hundreds of Unix programmers, I can assure you that test is not a good name. Now please find someone else to raise your non-issues with.

Comment: @unapersson: (a) You didn't. I'm pointing out a fact. Please look up the `a.out` format as you don't seem to know what it is. (b) You're painting your opinion as a fact, and one which many highly experienced professionals do not share. (c) You raised it. (d) I will not respond further to this conversation.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's how GCC and other *nix compilers have worked for years. They always output an `a.out` file, whether it's actually in a.out format or ELF or COFF. (On Windows, I think MinGW GCC actually outputs `a.exe`.) I'm not surprised Neil considers it irrelevant.

Comment: @greyfade: You're completely right. They've worked that way for years. It's unfortunate that it's the case, because the `a.out` format is obsolete. Just because that's the default output filename isn't reason to prefer it.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's not `a.out` he suggested preferring. He seems quite explicit in preferring *not* using a name like `test`.

Comment: @greyfade: His preference is to omit a name like `test`; perhaps I'm missing something, but his recommendation appears to be omitting the `-o` parameter, which produces an output file called `a.out`.

Comment: @Tomalak: My takeaway is that it's unimportant and unrelated to the question, and hence requiring no discussion.

Comment: @greyfade: You may be right there. I thought it worth bringing up as a passing point, but I'm starting to regret that now. :)

Comment: Naming an executable `test` is something that I have learned the hard way to regret and I am "perfectly capable of using a shell". It is a bad idea, and I've seen it bite many others who are "perfectly capable of using a shell".

Comment: @JamesKPolk if you have `.` in your `$PATH` you will certainly regret *something* at one point or another.

Comment: @n.m. It's not about having `.` in your path, but rather the other way around. You run `test`, forgetting correctly run it as `./test`, and instead of getting `command not found` it simply returns without error (or output).

Answer (score 57):

You can create a `.a` file using the `ar` utility, like so:

```
ar crf lib/libHeader.a header.o
```

`lib` is a directory that contains all your libraries. it is good practice to organise your code this way and separate the code and the object files. Having everything in one directory generally looks ugly. The above line creates `libHeader.a` in the directory `lib`. So, in your current directory, do:

```
mkdir lib
```

Then run the above `ar` command.

When linking all libraries, you can do it like so:

```
g++ test.o -L./lib -lHeader -o test
```

The `-L` flag will get `g++` to add the `lib/` directory to the path. This way, `g++` knows what directory to search when looking for `libHeader`. `-llibHeader` flags the specific library to link.

where test.o is created like so:

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
```

Comment: and what is with lib/libHeader.a? ar rcs ...isn't it better than ar crf?

Comment: @linuxx: main.o will be the object file you create out of main.cc

Comment: @linuxx: the exact flags you use with the ar utility are your decision based on your requirements. Looking up the man pages for ar would be a good idea.

Comment: how to test the library using test.cpp?

Comment: Replace main in the above code with test and C with cpp. In other words, my main.C (that I have used for illustration) and your test.cpp are, in all likelihood, equivalent.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is main.o? In my code i have header.cpp, header.h and the test.cpp(the code where i would like to test the header.a library).

Comment: Wouldn't it be `-lHeader` instead of `-llibHeader` ?

Comment: This is a great answer and he have OP more than he asked for

Answer (score 35):

> Can someone please tell me how to
>   create a static library from a .cpp
>   and a .hpp file? Do I need to create
>   the .o and the the .a?

Yes.

**Create the .o** (as per normal):

```
g++ -c header.cpp
```

**Create the archive**:

```
ar rvs header.a header.o
```

**Test**:

```
g++ test.cpp header.a -o executable_name
```

---

Note that it seems a bit pointless to make an archive with just one module in it. You could just as easily have written:

```
g++ test.cpp header.cpp -o executable_name
```

Still, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that your actual use case is a bit more complex, with more modules.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do we include multiple modules?

Comment: Good one! Sometimes we see `ranlib` which in GNU simply means `ar s`.