# Produce static libs from tensorflow_cc and tensorflow_framework

Tags: tensorflow, static-linking, bazel

As far as I understand using bazel I can only produce `libtensorflow_cc.so` and `libtensorflow_framework.so`.
I need to produce **static libs** that are position independent (`-fPIC`) because I'll link them to a dynamic lib of my own later.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257312/3659011) which suggest the use of a Makefile included in the project.
I successfully used it to replace the `libtensorflow_cc.so` but what can I do to replace `libtensorflow_framework.so`?

Answer (score 4):

Not an actual answer, but too long for a comment.

I managed to do something like what you mention using Bazel on Windows. In particular, I wanted to make a single wrapper DLL with one or two headers (limited in functionality) that I could move around easily. I'll write a summary of the things that I did; it's rather convoluted an customized for our needs, but maybe you find something useful.

- I pass `--config=monolithic` to the `bazel build` command (besides any other option that you need). That will avoid modularizing the library and thus remove the dependency to a `libtensorflow_framework.so` (see
  [tools/bazel.rc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tools/bazel.rc)).
- The goal that I build is not any of the ones in the TensorFlow repository. Instead, I add a very small program that uses my wrapper as a new Bazel target (a C++ file plus my headers headers and a `BUILD` file). So all of TensorFlow had to be compiled beforehand in order to compile this final dummy program.
- When I get that done, I take advantage of the fact that Bazel does already compile every subgoal as a static library. I check a file under the `bazel-bin` directory generated for my dummy program goal with a name ending `.params` - there I find the path of all the static libraries that were used to compile it.
- I copy all of these intermediate static libraries to somewhere else. Also, I copy a bunch of headers I will need to compile my final wrapper (TensorFlow own's, but also Eigen, Protobuf and Nsync now too). I put all of this in a build area I have prepared before.
- I use NMake Makefile to produce my custom DLL, using the static libraries, the copied headers and my own thin wrapper.

And that's about it, I think. I have an ugly Bash script I run on MSYS2 that does everything for me. Usually with every new release I need to tweak one or two things (some option in the `configure` script, some additional headers I need to copy, etc.), but I do get it to work in the end. It's quite a lot of fiddling though, so I'm not necessarily saying you should use the same approach (but feel free to ask for details about any step if you want).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-2.params` files @jdehesa mentioned and bazel verbose output (`-s` switch), you can even create a link command to eventually statically link these intermediate static libraries. I automated this process for Windows/Linux/macOS and included it to the [vcpkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/build/vcpkg) package manager. To use it just run `vcpkg install tensorflow:x64-windows-static`. If you're interested in the sources, you'll find them [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/tensorflow-common).