# Build Tensorflow on one system, deploy on another

Tags: windows, tensorflow, deployment

How can I deploy [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) on a different computer from the one I build it on? Which files need to be copied across? Building from source on each and every target PC is impractical. In my case I need to build from source since the standard install of `TensorFlow` is not optimized for my target (non-GPU build but with AVX/AVX2 available), not that that should make any difference. I am building & deploying on Windows PCs, which almost certainly will make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think: `python`. `Tensorflow` is essentially a python package, and python packages are installed with `pip`.

In this specific case, the standard installation of `TensorFlow` (version 1.5) was easily installed on my target system using `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` as per [standard TensorFlow instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). But when I tested examples I had already developed I was warned that the install was not optimal, since `AVX` and `AVX2` instructions were available, but not being used.

To rebuild `Tensorflow` from source to make use of `AVX2`, follow [instructions here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), in particular:

- Obtain the source from github: `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- Choose either the Bazel or CMake build option (I chose `CMake`, which required `SWIG`)
- Customise the build to specify use of `AVX` or `AVX2` (for me, I added `-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX2` to the options during the `CMake` step)
- build the tensorflow python pip package (very last instruction in the `CMake` step-by-step instructions)

Once you have the package (a `wheel` or `.whl`) file, move it to the target PC, and install it using `pip3 install tensorflow-<version-specific-details>.whl`.

This process has been tested on:

- Development PC: Windows 7-64 bit, Python 3.6.4 (64-bit), SWIG 3.0.12
- Target PC: Windows 8.1 Pro (64-bit), Python 3.6.4 (64-bit)

For the record, the use of `AVX2` instructions gave me approximately a 20% speed increase on my network training. Also, despite one of the known limitations being the need to use Python 3.5 for the CMake build, I have found no issue (so far) using Python 3.6.4.