# How to use static library in linux executable

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

I have a project which I compile on Linux. When I run the `ldd` command against the executable, here's what I get:

```
libevent_core-2.1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_core-2.1.so.6 (0x00007fca87a5e000)
libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.6 (0x00007fca8785b000)
```

Now, I want to make these libraries compile as static libraries. How can I do that?

Here's my make file library:

```
LIBS    = -levent_core -levent_extra -levent -levent_pthreads -lsystemd
```

Comment: I don't believe you can without the source.  shared libraries are compiled compiled with as position independent addressing `-fPIC` so without the code I think your out of luck.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you.  Is this your code?

Comment: @jiveturkey No this is not my code. I have source code files but i just need to make some library as static instead of dynamic. i have mentioned libraries which i want to convert to static and i have make file which i need to change.

Comment: You need to use `ar` to create the library after compiling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947067/how-to-create-a-static-library-with-g

Comment: @jiveturkey i already have .a file in dev package of libevent, i just need to make it as static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no makefile magic that turns shared libraries into static libraries.
You need to install the static versions of the libraries on your system and
then, in your makefile, specify that the static versions of the libraries are to
be linked.

It appears that the static libraries you would need to install are:

```
libevent_core.a
libevent_extra.a
libevent.a
libevent_pthreads.a
libsystemd.a
```

Having installed those libraries, you would modify your makefile to link them
statically by changing:

```
LIBS    = -levent_core -levent_extra -levent -levent_pthreads -lsystemd
```

to:

```
LIBS    = -Wl,-Bstatic -levent_core -levent_extra -levent -levent_pthreads -lsystemd -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

*However*, you cannot do exactly that, because there is no static version of `libsystemd`. [Here's why](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-March/017493.html).

There are static versions of the other libraries in your list. You can install them
by installing the `libevent` development package (probably package `libevent-dev` or `libevent-devel`,
depending on your linux distro). Then you can link those ones statically with:

```
LIBS    = -Wl,-Bstatic -levent_core -levent_extra -levent -levent_pthreads -Wl,-Bdynamic -lsystemd
```

*Note* that there are no spaces within `-Wl,-Bstatic` or `-Wl,-Bdynamic`. GCC options of the form `-Wl,...` mean that GCC should pass the options `...` through to its invocation of the linker.

Here is [the documentation of the linker options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)

Comment: Thanks for help. You are right, i dont need systemd lib as static. I tried to change my make file as you suggested but i am getting following error when i compile through make -f Makefile : /usr/bin/ld: cannnot find: No such file or directory. Collect2 : error: ld returned 1 exist status.

Comment: @RookieDev `/usr/bin/ld: cannnot find:` is not the complete error message. You have left out the library that it cannot find.

Comment: gcc -o aftpd aftpd.o cmd_parse.o fs_malloc.o ftpcmd.o ftpdata.o string.o fs_vector.o ./linux/loglinux.o ./linux/systemd.o  -Wl, -Bstatic -levent_core -levent_extra -levent -levent_pthreads -Wl, -Bdynamic -lsystemd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'aftpd' failed
make: *** [aftpd] Error 1   @Mike Kinghan This is my full error message

Comment: @RookieDev `-Wl, -Bstatic` is wrong. `-Wl,-Bstatic` is right. There is no space in the
middle. That is the cause of `cannot find : No such file or directory`. The same
with `-Wl, -Bdynamic`.