# Why is linking to cuda runtime still necessary for library user even when compiling with -cudart static

Tags: c++, cuda, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have some simple cuda code that I am compiling to a static library using `nvcc`, and some user code that I am compiling with `g++` and linking against the previously compiled static library. When attempting link, I get linker errors for things like `cudaMalloc` even if I use the `-cudart static` option in the `nvcc` compile command line.

Here is my code:

```
//kern.hpp
#include <cstddef>

class Kern
{
    private:
        float* d_data;
        size_t size;

    public:
        Kern(size_t s);
        ~Kern();
        void set_data(float *d); 
};
```

```
//kern.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <kern.hpp>

__global__ void kern(float* data, size_t size)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(idx < size) 
    {
        data[idx] = 0;
    }
} 

Kern::Kern(size_t s) : size(s)
{
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, size*sizeof(float));
}

Kern::~Kern()
{
    cudaFree(d_data);
}

void Kern::set_data(float* d)
{
    size_t grid_size = size;
    std::cout << "Starting kernel with grid size " << grid_size << " and block size " << 1 <<
        std::endl;
    kern<<<grid_size, 1>>>(d_data, size);
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if(err != cudaSuccess)
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy((void*)d, (void*)d_data, size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <kern.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "starting" << std::endl;
    Kern k(256);
    float arr[256];
    k.set_data(arr);
    bool ok = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) ok &= arr[i] == 0;
    std::cout << (ok ? "done" : "wrong") << std::endl;
}
```

I am compiling the kern with `nvcc` as follows:

```
nvcc -I ./ -lib --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o libkern.a kern.cu -cudart static
```

And then main with `g++` as follows:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -I ./ -L. -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -lkern
```

Which produces the errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `Kern::Kern(unsigned long)':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `Kern::~Kern()':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `cudaFree'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `Kern::set_data(float*)':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x152): undefined reference to `__cudaPushCallConfiguration'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to `cudaGetLastError'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `cudaGetErrorString'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `cudaDeviceSynchronize'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `cudaDeviceSynchronize'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `__nv_init_managed_rt_with_module(void**)':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `__cudaInitModule'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `__device_stub__Z4kernPfm(float*, unsigned long)':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to `__cudaPopCallConfiguration'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void**)':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x430): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFunction'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x44b): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x47c): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinaryEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libkern.a(tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-8_kern.o): in function `cudaError cudaLaunchKernel<char>(char const*, dim3, dim3, void**, unsigned long, CUstream_st*)':
tmpxft_00001d30_00000000-5_kern.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4d9): undefined reference to `cudaLaunchKernel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But if I do the following:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -I ./ -L. -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -lkern -lcudart
```

everything works.
My question is that since I have a `-cudart static` in the `nvcc` compiled line, shouldn't the `libkern.a` already have the symbols for the cuda runtime resolved? Why is the `-lcudart` still necessary in the `g++` line?

Also, if I change `libkern.a` to a shared object, not linking to the cuda runtime in the `g++` line works. That is, the following works:

```
nvcc -I ./ -shared --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o libkern.so kern.cu -cudart static
g++ -o main main.cpp -I ./ -L. -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -lkern
```

Why does the static library version fail, but the shared object version work?

Note that I have tried the above scenarios after replacing `-cudart static` with `-lcudart_static` in the `nvcc` line, and there was no change in behavior from making that replacement. This is to be expected as the two options essentially do the same thing right?

I am on linux.

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 10.1.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any help and/or clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: You never linked the runtime library anywhere, so why is it a surprise?

Comment: yeah my bad, I completely misunderstood the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you study [the nvcc documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html), it is fairly evident that the `-lib` option creates a static library (and specifies no linking) whereas the `-shared` option creates a shared library, and specifies linking.  For example, excerpting:

> 4.2.2.1. --link (-link)
> Specify the default behavior: compile **and link** all input files.

> 4.2.2.2. --lib (-lib)
> Compile all input files into object files, if necessary, and add the results to the specified library output file.

> 4.2.3.11. --shared (-shared)
> Generate a shared library **during linking**.
> Use option --linker-options when other linker options are required for more control.

I believe this is more-or-less consistent with typical gcc/g++ usage.  If you do a google search on "g++ create static library" you'll get any number of [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947067/how-to-create-a-static-library-with-g) which indicate that you should basically do this:

```
g++ -c my_source_file.cpp ...
ar ...
```

In other words, compilation of source to object is specified, but no linking is specified.  To pick one example, `cudaMalloc` is part of the CUDA runtime library, and the connection to that would be done during the link phase.

`nvcc` is a fairly complex animal under the hood, but we should keep in mind that for certain functions it mostly uses the installed host toolchain.  This includes for compilation of host code, and it also includes the final link phase.

Combined with that, I believe what you're wanting to do here is "partial" linking or incremental linking.  Performing some of the final link phase, before the final link phase.

The GNU linker (again, what `nvcc` would use, under the hood, on linux, by default) [supports that](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), so if we leave aside any concern for compilation of relocatable device code, it should be possible to do what you want as follows:

```
$ nvcc  -Xcompiler '-fPIC' -I.  -c kern.cu
$ ld -o kern.ro -r kern.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart_static -lculibos
$ ar rs libkern.a kern.ro
ar: creating libkern.a
$ g++ -o main main.cpp  -I ./ -L.  -lkern -lpthread -lrt -ldl
$ cuda-memcheck ./main
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
starting
Starting kernel with grid size 256 and block size 1
done
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Notes:

1. `-lpthread -lrt -ldl` are standard library dependencies of cudart/culibos, so these need to be provided for at final link phase, but they don't depend on any CUDA toolkit items.  If you desire these dependencies to also be removed from the incrementally linked object, I view that as a separate question, not related to CUDA.
2. The archive step (creation of the library) is not essential for this simple case.  We could have just passed the incrementally linked (`-r`) object `kern.ro` directly to the final compilation/link step.
3. Note that your CUDA install is evidently at a different location, so some of the above library paths (`-L`) may need to be changed.

Comment: I think I had completely misunderstood the documentation, very sorry. It compiles and links fine now. Thank you very much, your answer clarified a lot of things for me.