# Integrating a CUDA class into a C++ program

Tags: c++, class, cuda, linker

I have a C++ project where I need to integrate some CUDA into an existing codebase to take advantage of cuSPARSE and cuBLAS.  The CUDA portion of the code would be called fairly often (like inside a `for` loop), so if I were to use:

```
extern "C" void doStuff(int N, double *arg1, double* arg2);
```

as is suggested by `cppIntegration` in NVIDIA Sample codes, things I would ideally like to keep on device memory between calls would have be transferred at each call.  Is there any way around that?  Is it possible to create a class for CUDA stuff that lives during program lifetime and call something like

```
extern "C" class stuffHandler;
```

and then from my C++ program invoke:

```
stuff_handler.doStuff();
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have a C++ project

> Is it possible to create a class for CUDA stuff that lives during program lifetime

Sure.  I'm not sure what the `extern "C"` stuff has to do with a C++ project.  CUDA is a C++ type of language definition.

Here is an example:

```
$ cat t1901.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

__global__ void my_work(int N, double *X, double *Y, double *scale){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < N)
    Y[idx] += X[idx] * (*scale);
}

class stuffHandler
{
  double persistent;
  double *dev_persistent = NULL;
  public:
    stuffHandler(double persistent_) : persistent(persistent_) {
      cudaMalloc(&dev_persistent, sizeof(double));
      cudaMemcpy(dev_persistent, &persistent, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);}
    void doStuff(int N, double *arg1, double *arg2){
      double *d_arg1, *d_arg2;
      cudaMalloc(&d_arg1, N*sizeof(double));
      cudaMalloc(&d_arg2, N*sizeof(double));
      cudaMemcpy(d_arg1, arg1, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(d_arg2, arg2, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      my_work<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, d_arg1, d_arg2, dev_persistent);
      cudaMemcpy(arg2, d_arg2, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      cudaFree(d_arg1);
      cudaFree(d_arg2);}
    ~stuffHandler(){if (dev_persistent) cudaFree(dev_persistent);}
};

int main(){
  int my_N = 4;
  double scale = 1.5;
  stuffHandler stuff_handler(scale);
  std::vector<double> v1(my_N, 0.1);
  std::vector<double> v2(my_N, 0.2);
  stuff_handler.doStuff(my_N, v1.data(), v2.data());
  std::cout << v2[0] << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1901 t1901.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t1901
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0.35
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Responding to a question in the comments, you could rearrange the above as follows for a typical multi-module project implementation:

```
$ cat t1901.h

class stuffHandler
{
  double persistent;
  double *dev_persistent = NULL;
  public:
    stuffHandler(double persistent_);
    void doStuff(int N, double *arg1, double *arg2);
    ~stuffHandler();
};

$ cat t1901.cu
#include "t1901.h"

__global__ void my_work(int N, double *X, double *Y, double *scale){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < N)
    Y[idx] += X[idx] * (*scale);
}

stuffHandler::stuffHandler(double persistent_) : persistent(persistent_) {
      cudaMalloc(&dev_persistent, sizeof(double));
      cudaMemcpy(dev_persistent, &persistent, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);}
void stuffHandler::doStuff(int N, double *arg1, double *arg2){
      double *d_arg1, *d_arg2;
      cudaMalloc(&d_arg1, N*sizeof(double));
      cudaMalloc(&d_arg2, N*sizeof(double));
      cudaMemcpy(d_arg1, arg1, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(d_arg2, arg2, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      my_work<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, d_arg1, d_arg2, dev_persistent);
      cudaMemcpy(arg2, d_arg2, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      cudaFree(d_arg1);
      cudaFree(d_arg2);}
stuffHandler::~stuffHandler(){if (dev_persistent) cudaFree(dev_persistent);}
$ cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "t1901.h"

int main(){
  int my_N = 4;
  double scale = 1.5;
  stuffHandler stuff_handler(scale);
  std::vector<double> v1(my_N, 0.1);
  std::vector<double> v2(my_N, 0.2);
  stuff_handler.doStuff(my_N, v1.data(), v2.data());
  std::cout << v2[0] << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1901 t1901.cu main.cpp
$ compute-sanitizer ./t1901
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0.35
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

If you wanted to break the compilation and linking steps apart, you could do:

```
nvcc -c t1901.cu
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ main.o t1901.o -o test -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

Or in an MPI project, replace the above `g++` with `mpicxx`

After some additional discussion in the comments, contrary to your question title and first sentence, you actually have a C project, not C++ (you are wanting to do the final link with `mpicc` which is a C compiler).

In that case we could lay out the above code somewhat differently, and refer to some instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860375/why-is-linking-to-cuda-runtime-still-necessary-for-library-user-even-when-compil/62862718#62862718) for getting all of our C++ linking in order.  Here is another example:

```
$ cat t1902.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void C_init(double scale);
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void C_doStuff(int N, double *arg1, double *arg2);
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void C_end();
$ cat t1902.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

__global__ void my_work(int N, double *X, double *Y, double *scale){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < N)
    Y[idx] += X[idx] * (*scale);
}

class stuffHandler
{
  double persistent;
  double *dev_persistent = NULL;
  public:
    stuffHandler(double persistent_) : persistent(persistent_) {
      cudaMalloc(&dev_persistent, sizeof(double));
      cudaMemcpy(dev_persistent, &persistent, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);}
    void doStuff(int N, double *arg1, double *arg2){
      double *d_arg1, *d_arg2;
      cudaMalloc(&d_arg1, N*sizeof(double));
      cudaMalloc(&d_arg2, N*sizeof(double));
      cudaMemcpy(d_arg1, arg1, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(d_arg2, arg2, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      my_work<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, d_arg1, d_arg2, dev_persistent);
      cudaMemcpy(arg2, d_arg2, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      cudaFree(d_arg1);
      cudaFree(d_arg2);}
    void finish(){if (dev_persistent) cudaFree(dev_persistent);}
};

stuffHandler *stuff_handler = NULL;
extern "C" void C_doStuff(int N, double *arg1, double *arg2){
  if (stuff_handler)
    stuff_handler->doStuff(N, arg1, arg2);
}
extern "C" void C_end(){
  if (stuff_handler) {
    stuff_handler->finish();
    delete stuff_handler;}
  stuff_handler = NULL;
}
extern "C" void C_init(double scale){
  if (stuff_handler) C_end();
  stuff_handler = new stuffHandler(scale);
}
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "t1902.h"

int main(){
  int i,my_N = 4;
  double scale = 1.5;
  C_init(scale);
  double *d1 = malloc(my_N*sizeof(double));
  double *d2 = malloc(my_N*sizeof(double));
  for (i=0; i < my_N; i++) {
    d1[i] = 0.1;
    d2[i] = 0.2;}
  C_doStuff(my_N, d1, d2);
  printf("%f\n", d2[0]);
  C_end();
}
$ nvcc -c t1902.cu
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gcc -o test main.o t1902.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart_static -lculibos -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lstdc++
$ compute-sanitizer ./test
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0.350000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

In the compilation sequence above, it should be possible to replace `gcc` with `mpicc`.

Comment: The project I need to integrate CUDA into is compiled with `mpicc`, so I need to compile the CUDA portion of the code with `nvcc`, and then link with `mpicc`.  I can't have a CUDA enabled class in an `.h` be read by `mpicc`, and therefore cannot include it into that larger project with `#include "CUDAclass.h"` which might at some point need to run a method from this class

Comment: Probably good to include that sort of information in your question.  I've updated my answer with a roadmap.  If your question now becomes "how do I include code compiled with C++/mpicxx in  a C-style/mpicc project" I suggest you ask that as a separate question, it is orthogonal to CUDA.  It has also been asked/answered many times already.

Comment: I've already addressed that.  And if your question is how to compile a `.cpp` file with `mpicc`, please ask that separately.  It has nothing to do with CUDA.  And it also doesn't make sense to me.  A `.cpp` file is indicating that it contains C++ source code.  `mpicc` is a C compiler, by definition, not a C++ compiler.  The corresponding entity in MPI land for C++ is `mpicxx`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and sorry for the confusions!  In my "equivalent" `t1901.h`, I have `#include "cuda_runtime.h"`, when compile with `mpixx`, I have this warning:
`/usr/local/cuda-11.4/include/cuda_bf16.hpp:428:5: warning: "__CUDA_ARCH__" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]                                                                           
 #if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 800`
which is what started me off with the question initially.

I'll rephrase the problem I have more clearly in another thread.

Comment: The way I have my suggestion laid out, you don't need to `#include "cuda_runtime.h"` in `t1901.h`.  And I don't know what `mpixx` is, and I don't know which module you are compiling.  `cuda_runtime.h` can be parsed by a C++ compiler.  The CUDA runtime API is all consumable by a C++ compiler.  Actual CUDA device code is not, but the warning you have there has nothing to do with CUDA device code, or anything that a C++ compiler wouldn't be able to parse.